# Python: How to use shutil.copy() with unicode filenames

Tags: python, unicode

So I've been pounding my head against this problem for days and I just can't figure it out.  I've read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523373/python-how-to-move-a-file-with-unicode-filename-to-a-unicode-folder) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173477/copying-files-with-unicode-names) and feel like I must be missing something.

I'm trying to copy a simple text file with a complex unicode title into a temp folder with this code:

```
self._temp_path = tempfile.mkdtemp()
self.src = os.path.join(self._temp_path, 'src')
os.makedirs(self.src)
self.dst = os.path.join(self._temp_path, 'dst')
os.makedirs(self.dst)
self.dirname = dirname = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'testfiles')
f = u'file-\xe3\x82\xa8\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x83\x89\xe3\x83\xac\xe3\x82\xb9.txt'
src = os.path.join(dirname, f)
dst = os.path.join(self.src, f)
shutil.copy2(src, dst)
```

And I receive the following message when I execute the test:

```
s = '/tmp/tmpc1gzwf/src/file-ã¨ã³ãã¬ã¹.txt'
>           st = os.stat(s)
E           UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 24-38: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried using both shutil.copy and shutil.copy2, they produced identical results.  I've also tried changing:

```
shutil.copy2(src, dst)
```

to:

```
shutil.copy2(src.encode('utf-8'), dst.encode('utf-8'))
```

But that resulted in this error message, due to the encoding mangling the filename:

```
src = '/home/phil/projects/unicode_copy/tests/testfiles/file-\xc3\xa3\xc2\x82\xc2\xa8\xc3\xa3\xc2\x83\xc2\xb3\xc3\xa3\xc2\x83\xc2\x89\xc3\xa3\xc2\x83\xc2\xac\xc3\xa3\xc2\x82\xc2\xb9.txt'
dst = '/tmp/tmpCsb3qW/src/file-\xc3\xa3\xc2\x82\xc2\xa8\xc3\xa3\xc2\x83\xc2\xb3\xc3\xa3\xc2\x83\xc2\x89\xc3\xa3\xc2\x83\xc2\xac\xc3\xa3\xc2\x82\xc2\xb9.txt'
def copyfile(src, dst):
...
>       with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
E       IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/phil/projects/unicode_copy/tests/testfiles/file-\xc3\xa3\xc2\x82\xc2\xa8\xc3\xa3\xc2\x83\xc2\xb3\xc3\xa3\xc2\x83\xc2\x89\xc3\xa3\xc2\x83\xc2\xac\xc3\xa3\xc2\x82\xc2\xb9.txt'
```

After trying many other combinations of encode() and decode() at various points in the code, I've given up.  What is the proper way to declare a unicode filename and pass it to shutil.copy?

Comment: Are … are you sure that the filename isn't `'file-エンドレス.txt'`?

Comment: You can try to use `os.listdir(src)` which will give you all files in the src directory. this should allow you to select the file without explicit writing in the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quickly ran the following code based on your code on my system and it seems to work just fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import shutil
import tempfile

from pathlib import Path


class Code():

    def run(self):
        self._temp_path = Path(tempfile.mkdtemp())
        self.dstdir = self._temp_path / 'dst'
        os.makedirs(self.dstdir)

        self.srcdir = Path(os.path.dirname(__file__)) / 'testfiles'
        filename = u'file-\xe3\x82\xa8\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x83\x89\xe3\x83\xac\xe3\x82\xb9.txt'

        self.srcpath = self.srcdir / filename
        self.dstpath = self.dstdir / filename

        with open(self.srcpath, 'w') as f:
            f.write('test')

        shutil.copy2(self.srcpath, self.dstpath)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    code = Code()
    code.run()
    print(code.dstpath)
```

Sample output is `/tmp/tmpgqwktb_v/dst/file-ã¨ã³ãã¬ã¹.txt`.

Possible reasons are:

- I'm using Python3, which has notable better unicode support
- I'm running Linux in the en_GB.UTF-8 locale
- The second line of my script, declaring the encoding of the source

Perhaps the differences with your environment can explain your error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you sir!  Never thought to check my environment variables.  Turns out the user I was logged in as had the LANG set to POSIX... switched it over to en_US.UTF-8 and now the code works perfect.

Comment: My pleasure! Encodings and locales can be hard to deal with sometimes. Make a rule out of always configuring UTF-8 (if that suits your purpose of course) and you'll save yourself a lot of headaches. :-)